# Does IntelliJ IDEA have a `Ctrl` + `K`, `Ctrl` + `D` equivalent?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am used to Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut to quickly tidy up my C# code, does an equivalent exist in Intellij IDEA for Java?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The format code shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

Here's a [list of keyboard shortcuts in IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse](http://www.catalysts.cc/wissenswertes/intellij-idea-and-eclipse-shortcuts/?lang=en).

Also note that you can [configure shortcuts yourself](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and follow the options.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the keyboard shortcuts in [Help Menu] -> [Default Keymap Reference]. It is an excellent PDF that you can print and keep next to your keyboard.